# Distinct Join Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Video has many Events

I am trying to get all Videos that have Events scheduled in the future.

I have this which was already there:

```
named_scope :scheduled_in_future, :joins => :event, :conditions => ["event.scheduled_start > ? AND event.status = ?", Time.now.to_i, 'PENDING']
```

This works, but if the same Video has multiple events in the future it will give me duplicate Video records. Sure I can go through the array and weed out the duplicates, but there has to be a SQL way to do it.

I tried adding in a

```
:select => "DISTINCT(video.id)"
```

but it only returns the ID field instead of the whole record.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try using `:include` instead of `:joins` and you should not see any more duplicate video results.

Also, you should be using a lambda in your named_scope, otherwise `Time.now` will be cached the first time you use it and you'll start getting incorrect results.

```
named_scope :scheduled_in_future, lambda {
  { 
    :include => :events,
    :conditions => ["event.scheduled_start > ? AND event.status = ?", Time.now.to_i, 'PENDING']
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly. Also thanks for the lamba suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried grouping by the video id?

Comment: that gave me problems with PostgreSQL (Heroku) because all fields (except computed field with aggregation function) in the output must be present in the GROUP BY clause.