# Rails 3 DISTINCT QUERY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Have a User, UserBadge, and Badge table. They are connected through a has_many through. A user can have multiple of the same badge but I want to query a unique list.

```
@user.badges.select("DISTINCT id").order("created_at DESC")
```

It's throwing an error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near "DISTINCT": syntax error:
```

What would be the proper syntax?

EDIT: ADDED WHOLE ERROR

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near "DISTINCT": syntax error: SELECT "badges".*, DISTINCT badges.id FROM "badges" INNER JOIN "userbadges" ON "badges".id = "userbadges".badges_id WHERE (("userbadges".user_id = 1))
```

Could it be the comma between select and distinct?

Comment: you should include the whole error text in your question, there's something weird going on there.

Comment: The comma between the select and distinct is the problem. I'm having the same problem when I try a distinct select with a join. I think the problem is that Rails adds the first select clause whenever you have a join so that it only pulls the correct fields, then your `select` call adds another, and these are concatenated with commas. It seems to me like a bug in Rails.

Comment: Actually, John, try it without the distinct and see if you're actually seeing duplicate records. I removed the `DISTINCT` criteria from my query and it still works. In my Rails log I see two queries. The first query loads the ids for the join and the second query loads the models that I'm interested in. By doing it in two queries, it avoids having duplicate records caused by the join.

Comment: For some reasons, includes works better in that case that joins
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4749964/102133

Answer (score 27):

DISTINCT needs to be straight after the SELECT i.e.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(badges.id), "badges".* FROM "badges" INNER JOIN "userbadges" ON "badges".id = "userbadges".badges_id WHERE (("userbadges".user_id = 1))
```

Try:

```
@user.select("DISTINCT(badges.id), badges.*").badges.order("badges.created_at DESC")
```

PostgreSQL requires you have an order statement for the distinct field:

```
@user.select("DISTINCT(badges.id), badges.*").badges.order("badges.id").order("badges.created_at DESC")
```

Comment: The most important part here is the way to add badges.* or basically * to any select query where you want to order on the elements later.

Answer (score 21):

Could try using group

```
@user.badges.group(:id)
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly for my use case (which is the basically the same as the OP's)

Comment: for postgres you probably need to add a select statement.

Comment: See @Mike's answer for the PostgreSQL method of doing this.

Answer (score 7):

Set

```
:uniq => true
```

on the association. Or create a separate association just for a user's unique badges.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many

Something like

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_badges
  has_many :badges, :through => :user_badges
  has_many :unique_badges, :through => :user_badges, :source => :badges, :uniq => true
  #untested
end
```

Comment: Why doesn't this have more upvotes?  All the other answers seem backwards and overcomplicated, and this works fine.

Comment: @Alison , creating another association is very heavy and a bad solution.

Comment: @sidney creating another association isn't *really* that heavy and I would argue is not a bad solution.  If this makes sense for your use case, I think it's a valid approach.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
@user.badges.select("DISTINCT(badges.id)").order("badges.created_at DESC")
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, using PostgreSQL too.

My code looked like this:

```
User.find(2).devices.group('token')
```

Which caused an error:

```
Device Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "devices".* FROM "devices" WHERE "devices"."user_id" = 2 GROUP BY token
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  column "devices.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

**Solution:**

Changing that line to:

```
User.find(2).devices.select('distinct token')
```

Worked perfectly:

```
Device Load (1.3ms)  SELECT distinct token FROM "devices" WHERE "devices"."user_id" = 2
=> [#<Device token: "example">, #<Device token: "example1">, #<Device token: "example2">, #<Device token: "example3">, #<Device token: "example4">, #<Device token: "example4">]
```

**Update:**

Sorry, I haven't read the original question thoroughly and have actually responded to another post in the thread, complaining of the #group method not working with PostgreSQL. It's still a valuable answer though, so I'll leave it.

Answer (score 3):

There are at least three ways to get a unique list of badges from the user:

1. `@user.badges.group(:id)`
2. `@user.badges.select("DISTINCT badges.*")`
3. Or add `:uniq => true` in the `has_many :badges, :through` line

Of course, you can chain in your `order("badges.created_at DESC")` to the query also.

Answer (score 1):

```
@user.badges.select("id").order("created_at DESC").uniq
```

This one work for me.

Comment: Do you really need the call to .uniq ? Wouldn't that be redundant?