# SQL select distinct value

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to select the following data with the limited information. The problem is that when I have added the `.select` distinct section it has killed my query.

`@activities = Availability.select.("DISTINCT user_id").where("team_id = ? and schedule_id = ?", current_user[:team_id], @next_game).last(5)`

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901828/rails-3-distinct-query

Comment: doesnt really help, as its not using a WHERE cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's one too many dot's in there as the 'DISTINCT user_id' is the arguments for the select method call.
So:

```
Availability.select("DISTINCT user_id").where("team_id = ? and schedule_id = ?", current_user[:team_id], @next_game).last(5)
```

Also be aware that you're now only selecting one attribute and you'll get a partial representation of the classes back. To circumvent this just select the attributes you need later in the code.

```
Availability.select("DISTINCT(`user_id`), `team_id`").where("team_id = ? and schedule_id = ?", current_user[:team_id], @next_game).last(5)
```

etc.

Hope this helps.