# Rails ActiveRecord Model.uniq.pluck :id doesn't work with postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an empty demo rails 4 app trying to do the following: `Collection.order('created_at ASC').uniq.pluck :name` It works under sqlite, but blows up in postgres with the following error:

```
(0.9ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "collections"."name" FROM "collections" ORDER BY created_at ASC
PG::Error: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 1: ...collections"."name" FROM "collections"   ORDER BY created_at...
```

Is this a bug or how can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe a clearer use case is using `:name` or any other attributes. That's what I wanted to accomplish. Thanks.

Comment: It's not the ordering that's causing your problems, it's the uniq. Why do you have it? can you remove?

Comment: @JesseWolgamott Why is `#uniq` causing the problem? I also tried rails3. It looks like `uniq` is only a problem when used with `order`. I ended up not using `order`. But still puzzled by this behavior, cos it obviously does work in sqlite.

Comment: Well--- you can open a rails issue, or remove the uniq, which doesn't appear to be doing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was actually trying to solve this issue on active_admin. https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/2324

Now the solution seems to be `Collection.reorder('name asc').uniq.pluck :name`, this will overwrite the default_scope or previous order, and order collections with `name`. What's weird here is `reorder` works, while as `order` causes the problem...

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a problem with PostgreSQL. ([Rails 3 DISTINCT QUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901828/rails-3-distinct-query))

To solve it, you could use select instead:

`Collection.select([:name, :created_at]).order('created_at ASC').uniq.select(:name)`

Or you could have Ruby get the names uniquely rather than SQL:

`Collection.order('created_at ASC').pluck(:name).uniq`

Comment: Thanks. Your first solution still doesn't work under rails 4: `Collection.select([:name, :created_at]).order('created_at ASC').uniq.pluck(:name)` But I think the second one works. Just not sure about the performance impact, which I'm not too worried about. The `#pluck` method in ActiveRecord looks to be culprit. It also has been changed a lot since rails4. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Collection.select([:id, :created_at]).order('created_at ASC').uniq.pluck(:id)
```

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't work. `PG::Error: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 1: ... "collections"."id" FROM "collections"   ORDER BY created_at...
                                                             ^
: SELECT DISTINCT "collections"."id" FROM "collections"   ORDER BY created_at ASC
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 1: ... "collections"."id" FROM "collections"   ORDER BY created_at`

Comment: I tested it on rails 3.2, maybe 'select' method was changed, try: select("id, created_at")

Comment: Are you also using postgres? Same error. It actually works with just `Collection.order('created_at ASC').uniq`, as soon as I started with `pluck` it blows up. It works with sqlite though :(.

Comment: Yes, I'm testing it on postgres. The generated SQL is: `SELECT DISTINCT id, created_at, id FROM "users" ORDER BY created_at ASC`

Comment: I tested on another rails3 console, and your method indeed works! But sadly it doesn't work on rails4 somehow...