# how to add uniqueness on a .where call in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I cant find this in the docs and searching for it only shows results for adding uniqueness in the model.

How can I add uniqueness to a `.where` call. I want to have the below command not grab `CategoryItemValues` with the same `category_item_id`.

```
last_updated_items = CategoryItemValue.where(guide_id: @guide.id).order(updated_at: :desc).limit(5)
```

So the command grabs 5 of the most recently updated `CategoryItemValues` without getting 5 of them with the same `category_item_id`. if the `category_item_id` is the same as another most recently updated it skips it and adds the next most recently updated to the 5 results returned.

**Update**

doing this using the `select` method and using `distinct` still gives duplicate `category_item_id` for some reason

`CategoryItemValue.select(:category_item_id).distinct.where(guide_id: @guide.id).order(updated_at: :desc).limit(5).pluck(:category_item_id, :updated_at)`

`[[6, Wed, 11 May 2016 10:24:39 UTC +00:00], [3, Wed, 11 May 2016 10:21:20 UTC +00:00], [3, Wed, 11 May 2016 10:20:43 UTC +00:00], [6, Wed, 11 May 2016 09:14:14 UTC +00:00], [5, Wed, 11 May 2016 09:14:04 UTC +00:00]]`

notice the second and third array values both have 3 at the start. (plus im not sure if the comma after the day i the date time is going to effect pulling these values from the array)

Comment: @CharlesHamel how would I add that to this command?

Comment: last_updated_items = CategoryItemValue.where(guide: @guide).uniq I would also say thad your var name is not ok cause since it's uniq you should rename it last_updated_item with no "s"

Comment: .uniq just means if 2 records are the same one will be removed. In this case all records will be unique because the `updated_at` column will always be unique considering it goest down to the second it was updated, I need something like .uniq but on just the one column `category_item_id`

Comment: did you try to add .select ? Which is Select a,b,c from and does a uniq on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
CategoryItemValue.select(:category_item_id, "MIN(updated_at) as updated_at").distinct.where(guide_id: @guide_id).group(:category_item_id).order(updated_at: :desc).limit(5)
```

Both of these group the results set by category_item_id, and should return one record for each category item, with the oldest (MIN) value for `updated_at` of that category item.  The get the newest updated records, use MAX instead of MIN.

Comment: How do I get `updated_at` value for each record out of it?

Comment: @Rob I just updated the query to include an alias for the 2nd column, and named it `updated_at`.  You should be able to refer to it as `updated_at` just  like normal now.  It was an oversight in my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass SQL to an active record `where` clause. The method you're looking for is `DISTINCT` http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

You can also use the rails distinct method.

Try: `CategoryItemValue.select(:category_id).distinct.where(guide_id: @guide.id)`

This answer might also help: [Rails 3 DISTINCT QUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901828/rails-3-distinct-query)

Comment: I'm passing `.distinct` to it but it is making no difference as if it isn't even there `CategoryItemValue.where(guide_id: @guide.id).distinct(:category_item_id).order(updated_at: :desc).limit(5)`

Comment: I actually meant SQL but that should work, too. Try this: `CategoryItemValue.select(:guide_id).distinct.where(guide_id: @guide.id)`

Comment: Wont `select` just get the `guide_id`? not bring me the records themselves?

Comment: yes--but you can get the rest of the records. You could, for instance, pluck the ids. Or you could add an arg to select.

Comment: Here is what I have but once again `.distinct` is still letting through duplicate `category_item_id` . `CategoryItemValue.select(:category_item_id, :updated_at).distinct(:category_item_id).order(updated_at: :desc).limit(5)`

Comment: you don't need to include updated_at in the select in order to use it in order.

Comment: But I need to have the updated_at date. I found if i have `CategoryItemValue.select(:category_item_id).distinct.where(guide_id: @guide.id).order(updated_at: :desc).limit(5)` it works but I cant get the date it was updated

Comment: try out something like this: `User.select(:first_name).distinct.where(school_id: 2).pluck(:id, :updated_at)`

Comment: that returns this sql: `SELECT DISTINCT `users`.`id`, `users`.`updated_at` FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`school_id` = 2`

Comment: Check the update to my question it still duplicates the stupid `category_item_id`

Comment: What if you do this, and only this...get rid of extra stuff. Only do: `User.select(:first_name).distinct.first(5)` but with your model and the cat id. I know it's not everything you need (yet--it will be) but none are duplicated, correct?

Comment: Also post the SQL being returned, please. I'm going to bed in a sec.

Comment: That will only show the first 5 results that have a unique cat id I need the last 5 updated results. her is the output from what I have in my question ` SELECT  DISTINCT "category_item_values"."category_item_id", "category_item_values"."updated_at" FROM "category_item_values" WHERE "category_item_values"."guide_id" = ?  ORDER BY "category_item_values"."updated_at" DESC LIMIT 5`

Comment: I know man. Trying to walk you through it in pieces. But good luck.