# Filter model with multiple has many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Given

Document:

```
has_many :shares
has_many :groups, :through => :shares
```

User:

```
has_many :memberships
has_many :groups, :through => :memberships
```

Group:

```
has_many :memberships
has_many :users, :through => :memberships

has_many :shares
has_many :documents, :through => :shares
```

I need to show only documents for a given instance of User, current_user.

`@documents = current_user.groups.documents` doesn't cut it.

How can i filter down to only the documents that have at least on group in common with the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a single query:

```
Document.includes(:shares => { :group => :users }).where('users.id' => current_user.id)
```

Generated SQL (for `current_user.id = 1`):

```
SELECT "documents"."id" AS t0_r0, "documents"."created_at" AS t0_r1,
  "documents"."updated_at" AS t0_r2, "shares"."id" AS t1_r0,
  "shares"."group_id" AS t1_r1, "shares"."document_id" AS t1_r2,
  "shares"."created_at" AS t1_r3, "shares"."updated_at" AS t1_r4,
  "groups"."id" AS t2_r0, "groups"."created_at" AS t2_r1,
  "groups"."updated_at" AS t2_r2, "users"."id" AS t3_r0,
  "users"."created_at" AS t3_r1, "users"."updated_at" AS t3_r2
  FROM "documents"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "shares" ON "shares"."document_id" = "documents"."id"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "groups" ON "groups"."id" = "shares"."group_id"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "memberships" ON "memberships"."group_id" = "groups"."id"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "memberships"."user_id"
  WHERE "users"."id" = 1
```

Note that by using [`includes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) instead of [`joins`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins), only distinct results are returned (so no need to call `uniq` on the result). See: [Distinct Join Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749695/distinct-join-rails)

Comment: Problem with that approach is that if a document has 2 groups in common with the user it outputs that document 2 times. Adding .uniq to the end fixes it, but i'm not sure this is the best way to get to the result. Anyway, thanks for your input!

Comment: I agree it would be nice to do it in a cleaner way, but performance-wise the key issue is what queries it is making to the DB. With this approach you get two, first to find the groups associated with `current_user` (via `memberships`), then to select all documents that have those groups (via `shares`). That's the minimum you'll need to get the desired result.

Comment: Updated my answer: you can do this with a single DB query.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
docs = []
current_user.groups.uniq.each do |group|
   docs << group.documents
end
docs
```